# PHP license code implementation

Tags: php, licensing, activation

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement a activation license for PHP applications? Whilst I'm not planning on encrypting the source, and I'm not expecting there to be some magical way to stop people breaking the license check (people who want to do it, are going to do it anyway), I'd still like to find the balance between being annoying for people trying to break it, and being too annoying for me that it wouldn't be worth doing.

I'd like the license check to mainly work locally without having to call home, but also to on occasion call home to confirm (say once a day/week or something) if possible. Any thoughts on how to do it?

Comment: "without having to call home, but also to on occasion call home" wat

Comment: @JohnD: I think OP wants to say "contacting my licensing server"

Comment: http://www.php-protection.com/

Comment: @Kev that site doesn't really help me, as I said I didn't want to encode my php script. Also, I don't quite understand why you closed my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a simple licensekey system, and maybe setup your own "license" server to query all your systems for a valid license key once or two times a day. Maybe also implement a license check during login to your product.

What exactly are you building this for? A CMS, offline intranet software or?

Comment: I'm building a e-commerce plugin for a CMS. My concern with using a system that "contacts the licensing server" all the time might slow it down, or would be a problem if my licensing service broke down for any reason.